# How to count ending 0s in binary string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string: `11000000101010000000010000000000`

I would like to count the `0`s starting at the back until I hit `1` and stop there, determining the total number of `0`s at the end. In this particular case it would give me `10` as an answer.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit) and [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)

```
>>> s = '11000000101010000000010000000000'
>>> len(s.rsplit('1', 1)[-1])
10
```

Comment: To take advantage of `rsplit` (instead of just `split`), use the `maxsplit` argument: `s.rsplit('1', 1)`.  Also, no need for `count` once it's been `split`. Just use `len(s.rsplit('1',1)[-1])`

Comment: Another alternative: `len(s) - len(s.rstrip('0'))`

Comment: This will give incorrect results if the string doesn't contain any `1`s.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`rindex()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) to get the index of the last `1` and then subtract that from the maximum index (`len(s) - 1`):

```
>>> s = '11000000101010000000010000000000'
>>> len(s) - s.rindex('1') - 1
10
```

Comment: Good, but what about when it is all zeros?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski What would you expect the answer to be in that case? Raising an error (which `rindex` will do) seems most appropriate to me in such cases.

Comment: I don't know.  Depends on what OP is using the number for.  OP may want to return a count of zero, or total length.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in regex, because why not!

```
>>> s = '11000000101010000000010000000000'
>>> match = re.search('0*$', s)
>>> match.end() - match.start()
10
```

Comment: That was kinda my thinking: why not use a lambda and a couple of generators to answer this one!

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was answered already, but I thought I would add yet another way that you could do this.

You could use `itertools.takewhile` on the reverse of the string and `takewhile` the digit is not '1'. Apply a sum to all the 1s that were generated and you get the answer.

```
>>> test = "11000000101010000000010000000000"
>>> sum(1 for x in takewhile(lambda i: i != '1', test[::-1]))
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either :

- perform successive divisions by 10 on the corresponding integer taken as if it was in base 10.
- use strings operations to find the last 1 and take everything after it
- use regular expressions to get the 0s at the end and count them
- look for operations to convert to binary and perform successive divisions by two.

Answer (score 0):

```
binary_str = "11000000101010000000010000000000"

import re

match_obj = re.search(r"0*$", binary_str)

if match_obj:
    print len(match_obj.group())
```